# Pandoc: avoid paragraphs or add css class to paragraph?

Tags: markdown, pandoc, reveal.js

To create reveal.js slideshows, I would expect to use this:

```markdown
:::: { .r-stack }
![](img1){}
![](img2){.fragment}
::::
```

But this does not work, because pandoc wraps this in a paragraph, rendering the `.r-stack` disfunctional:

```html
<div class="r-stack">
<p><img src="img1" /> <img src="img2" class="fragment" /></p>
</div>
```

I can get this working by adding more paragraphs:

```markdown
:::: { .r-stack }
![](img1){}

![](img2){.fragment}
::::
```

which yields

```html
<div class="r-stack">
<p><img src="img1" /></p>
<p><img src="img2" class="fragment" /></p>
</div>
```

But I would rather avoid the additional paragraphs, pandoc goes a bit overboard on these.
I'd rather have a div only, or at least be able to add the css classes to the paragraph.

E.g., here

```markdown
:::: { .r-stack }
![](img1){}

[abc ![](img2)]{.fragment}
::::
```

which yields

```html
<div class="r-stack">
<p><img src="img1" /></p>
<p><span class="fragment">abc <img src="img2" /></span></p>
</div>
```

The span itself is not necessary, only the class, but I have not found a way to get

`<p class="fragment">abc <img src="img2" /></p>`

or

`<div class="fragment">abc <img src="img2" /></div>`

without going full HTML. Is there some trick that I missed?

Answer (score 2):

Pandoc interpretes the lines in fenced code blocks as `Para` objects.

To get the following HTML code

```html
<div class="r-stack">
<img src="img1" /> <img src="img2" class="fragment" />
</div>
```

you could use HTML native syntax instead of fenced code block with the option `-native_divs`:

```markdown
cat <<EOF | pandoc -f markdown-native_divs -t html
<div class="r-stack">
![](img1){}
![](img2){.fragment}
</div>
EOF
```

For more complex use cases I'd suggest to use a filter to replace `Para` with `Plain` when the parent `Div` has class `r-stack`
like the following:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from panflute import *

def action(elem: Element, doc: Doc):
    if type(elem) == Para:
        elem_parent = elem.parent
        if hasattr(elem_parent, 'classes'):
            if 'r-stack' in elem_parent.classes:
                p = Plain()
                p.content.extend(elem.content.list)
                return [p]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_filters([action])
```

And use as follows:

```markdown
cat <<EOF | pandoc -f markdown -t html --filter css_filter.py
::: {.r-stack}
![](img1){}
![](img2){.fragment}
:::
EOF
```

to get the following

```html
<div class="r-stack">
<img src="img1" /> <img src="img2" class="fragment" />
</div>
```