# Is there how to stop Pandoc from wrapping every line as a paragraph and from nesting the image into the list?

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

Good morning!

I was following the tutorial at [Pandoc: avoid paragraphs or add css class to paragraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75668017/pandoc-avoid-paragraphs-or-add-css-class-to-paragraph), but it does not solve my problem. I also gave a look for another question: [Disable pandoc convert the image’s alt text to a paragraph when docx to markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74759201/disable-pandoc-convert-the-image-s-alt-text-to-a-paragraph-when-docx-to-markdown).

Here is the small code:

```
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, reprehenderit.
2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit:

    ![example](assets/images/iuacessos-preferences.png)

3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim voluptates similique ab doloremque delectus veniam.
```

I ran the following:

```bash
pandoc bug.md -f markdown_github+fenced_divs-implicit_figures-native_divs+raw_html -t html -o bug.md
```

Here is the output:

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic,
      reprehenderit.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit:</p>
    <p><img src="assets/images/iuacessos-preferences.png" alt="example" /></p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim
      voluptates similique ab doloremque delectus veniam.</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

You can see that Pandoc adds `p` element in every line, in every element, including the `li` element. It also added `p` among the `img` element, and nested `p + img` inside the `li` element.

The code should be like:

```html
<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, reprehenderit.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit:</li>
    <img src="assets/images/iuacessos-preferences.png" alt="example" />
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim voluptates similique ab doloremque delectus veniam.</li>
</ol>
```

It is elegant and clean. Differently, GitHub has exactly this same output, doesn't wrap every line with a `p` element, and doesn't nest the image inside the `li` element.

Observe that I use mostly `markdown_github` because it supports more features than other Pandoc Markdown variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that recent pandoc versions say `Deprecated: markdown_github. Use gfm instead.`

So what you should be using is:

```
pandoc -f gfm -o bug.html bug.md
```

which will use the exact same markdown parser that github itself uses.

Note that the HTML you posted under "the code should be like" is invalid, since an `<ol>` can only have `<li>` as direct children. Perhpas you meant:

```html
<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, reprehenderit.</li>
  <li>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit:
    <img src="assets/images/iuacessos-preferences.png" alt="example" />
  </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim voluptates similique ab doloremque delectus veniam.</li>
</ol>
```

For which `pandoc -f html -t gfm` gives the correct markdown:

```
1.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic,
    reprehenderit.
2.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit:
    ![example](assets/images/iuacessos-preferences.png)
3.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim
    voluptates similique ab doloremque delectus veniam.
```

If you're wondering why you get the `<p>` around the image:

From [the MANUAL](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#paragraphs):

> A paragraph is one or more lines of text followed by one or more blank lines.

And why you get the `<p>` around the [list items](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#lists):

> A bullet list is a list of bulleted list items. A bulleted list item begins with a bullet (*, +, or -). Here is a simple example:
>
> ```
> * one
> * two
> * three
> ```
>
> This will produce a “compact” list. If you want a “loose” list, in which each item is formatted as a paragraph, put spaces between the items:
>
> ```
> * one
>
> * two
>
> * three
> ```

Comment: The problem is that I need to enable `simple_tables` for the Lua filter `list-tables` for Codebraid Preview. See the issue: https://github.com/pandoc-ext/list-table/issues/4. However, it worked on the terminal. Well, what the Markdown variants features caused to nest the `img` inside the `li` element? See the list of disabled and enabled `gfm` or `markdown_github` features below:

Comment: I understood what happened. I needed to add `<br/>` as I inspected the GitHub code.

Comment: But I can not use `gfm` as I depend on `list-tables` if I want to use Codebraid Preview.